# How to return all unordered list items including links and links text?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors, nodelist

**It takes no arguments**.
It returns all unordered list items (the ones that include links to Facebook, Instagram, and Twitter). They should be NodeList objects that are returned by function **querySelector** or **querySElectorAll.** Common mistake hint: we do not look only for the inner text of those items, we need **NodeList objects.**

**MY HTML Code.**

```
<div id="social">
    <ul>

     <li> <a class="social-media-links" href="https://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a> </li>


     <li> <a class="social-media-links" href="https://www.instagram.com">Instagram</a> </li> 


      <li> <a class="social-media-links" href="https://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a> </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

**MY javascript function code.**

```
function findAllUnorderedListElements() {
  
  e = document.querySelector('#social ul a');
 
console.log(e)
}
function prepareProjects() {
}
```

I will be thankful to you all my friends who can help me. I need help to solve this problem.

Comment: The question is unclear. And why did you add the `jquery-selectors` tag?

Comment: Because I need to return the unordered list items including link and link text.

Answer (score 0):

If I have not misunderstood, what you want is to create a list with all the social networks that appear unordered and getting the attributes of them to get the urls.

```js
function findAllUnorderedListElements() {
  return document.querySelectorAll('#social ul a');
}
function prepareProjects() {
  let list = findAllUnorderedListElements();
  let newObject = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    let item = list[i];

    newObject.push({
      url: item.href,
      label: item.innerHTML,
    });
  }

  console.log(newObject);
}

prepareProjects();
```

```html
<div id="social">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="social-media-links" href="https://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a class="social-media-links" href="https://www.instagram.com"
        >Instagram</a
      >
    </li>

    <li>
      <a class="social-media-links" href="https://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I didn't understand your question quite well, this is the solution I can give based on what I've understood.

```js
function findAllUnorderedListElements() {
  var e = document.querySelectorAll("#social > ul > li > a");

  console.log(e);
}
findAllUnorderedListElements();
```

```html
<div id="social">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="social-media-links" href="https://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
    <li> <a class="social-media-links" href="https://www.instagram.com">Instagram</a></li>
    <li> <a class="social-media-links" href="https://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's from Microverse I think. You're missing the return keyword. You have to type:

```
function findAllUnorderedListElements() {
    return document.querySelectorAll('ul li a');
}
```